# Microsoft SQL Server with Oracle SQL Developer on Mac

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, authentication, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm having trouble logging into our MS SQL Server 2008 from my Mac. My computer is not joined to the domain, which seems to matter, until I connect via VPN. Anyway, I have the JTDS driver running fine, I think. The error I get is a "Logon failed for user." So I know it is finding the server correctly. I can connect via FreeTDS in the terminal. I got the exact same error until I realized I needed to put my username as `'domain\username'` instead of just `username`. Of course I've tried all variations of this in Oracle SQL Developer. I've tried using the "Windows Authentication" thing but it doesn't help. I've read that sometimes Windows Authentication just doesn't work in Java apps. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This can be fixed by appending ";domain=your-windows-domain" to 'customURL' attribute in ~/.sqldeveloper/systemXXX/o.jdeveloper.db.connection./connections.xml  for every connection that you create.

see https://community.oracle.com/thread/2362216 for more info

Answer (score 1):

If you connect from any client you can use windows or internal authentication.
From non windows machine I prefer yusing internal sql authentication.
By default sql server authentication is deactivated on pre 2008 and on 2008 or 1012 you get asked by while you install the server. On all versions you can activate sql authentication on the sql server proeprties via the management studio.

So I would try sql auth first. Then if you really need windows authentication try use fqdn like username@domain.local with password. But in general you first attempt domain\username should work as well.

Comment: (For Drew) To be clear, SQL Server offers two ways of authenticating: Active Directory or Windows Authentication (default), and internal SQL Server authentication. For connecting from non-Windows hosts, or Hosts that don't belong to the SQL Server's domain, its generally easier to just reconfigure SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks for the info - unfortunately, though the `domain\username` _doesn't_ work. Also, I don't think I can really reconfigure the SQL Server. I don't have a whole lot of permissions.

Comment: Ask the admin if the internal auth is activated. Normally all do :) Then ask do add a user to the database and make him db_owner (or whatever) and use those instead.